# In Spark AR how to make object visible on screen, but not seen on the recording

Tags: spark-ar-studio

So i want to place a timer in my effect, but make it possible to see only during i record the video. But when you see the result - it shouldn't be on the recording. Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

so u can add a canvas and in the property u will see a option called enabled for . and in that uncheck the on recording or on capture it will do the trick. u can do this to the canvas object

Comment: it doesen't work, unfortrunately. that was litteraly the first thing i did. it still keep showing the canvas on the recording

Comment: capture is disabled -  [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/85KqjO8.png)
patch with visibility of canvas - [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/MvvMTVk.png)
result of recording - [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/KwOzLrf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue too - I disabled the canvas for Capture, but it still displayed the canvas text when I played it back in the Spark AR Player.

Turns out, the text was not actually visible in the file actually saved to the "My Files" section of my phone. It only showed up when I played it back from the Spark AR Player app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).